# how to enable trace in business layer project or data acess layer projects?

Tags: asp.net, trace, three-tier

I have 3 projects in a solution, out of which one is data access layer project , another one is reporting project and the main project. 
How do i enable and veiw tracing in DAL and Reporting Project?
I am able to see tracing done in main project. and i am able to write trace.write in dal and reporting project, but unable to see them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way.
we need to add the following two steps into the corresponding web.config files.
3 projects, 3 web.config files.

Step 1. under 
`<System.Web>`
`<trace pageOutput="true"`
`enabled="true"`
`requestLimit="10"`
`localOnly="false"`
`mostRecent="true"`
`traceMode="SortByTime"`
`/>`
Step 2. 
`<system.diagnostics>`
`<trace autoflush="true">`
`<listeners>`
`<add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"`initializeData="c:\myListener.log" /> 
 
 
`</system.diagnostics>`